# how to remove Geojson data from leaft without removing the base map?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to create a weather forecast app using ionic 3.  I need to be show various forecast like rain, temp etc, which the user can select via a fabicon. As of now when I go to the page the first data which is added from a geojson is showing on the page correctly, but when i change the the fab e.g from rain to temperature, the data is plotted but the map is disappearing as in the image below. I have tired clearlayers as well as removelayer but both gives me same result. I need to be able to show the new data without removing the map. Following is my code.

```
     updateFAB(fc, fab:FabContainer){
        fab.close();
        this.forecast = fc;
        console.log('forecast', this.forecast);
        console.log('forecast date', this.date);
        this.base_url = "";
        // geojsonLayer =  null;
        if(this.forecast == 'rainfall'){
            this.map.removeLayer(maingeojsonLayer);
            this.base_url = 'someurl';
        } else if (this.forecast == 'tmax'){
            this.map.removeLayer(maingeojsonLayer);
            this.base_url = 'someurl';
        } else if (this.forecast == 'tmin'){
            this.map.removeLayer(maingeojsonLayer);
            this.base_url = 'some url';
        }
        this.presentToast('Fetching new data....');
        this.updateForecast();
      }

    updateForecast(){
    geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(this.base_url,
    {
      style: function(feature){
        return {
          fillColor: feature.properties['fill'],
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          color: feature.properties['stroke'],
          opacity: 0.7,
          weight: 0.0,
        }
      },
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
        var title =  feature.properties.title;
        var fill_color = feature.properties.fill;
        var stroke_color = feature.properties.stroke;
        console.log('title', title);
        layer.on('click', (event) => {
          console.log("clicked");
          var value = feature.properties['title'] + 'mm';
          console.log("value", value);
          layer.bindPopup(value).openPopup();
        });
      }
    });
    // geojsonLayer.addTo(this.map);
    // geojsonLayer.addTo(maingeojsonLayer);     
    maingeojsonLayer.addTo(this.map);
    maingeojsonLayer.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
  }
```

geojson layer and maingeojson layer are globally declared

[image: This is what I am currently getting after trying to removelayer, clearlayers]

Comment: Try `maingeojsonLayer.remove()`.

Comment: doesnt work. Still getting the same result. The map is disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution works fine for me:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        layers: [googleStreets],
        .......
        .......
        zoomControl: false
    });

var forecastLayer;
updateForecast(){
forecastLayer= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(this.base_url,
{
  style: function(feature){
    return {
      fillColor: feature.properties['fill'],
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      color: feature.properties['stroke'],
      opacity: 0.7,
      weight: 0.0,
    }
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    var title =  feature.properties.title;
    var fill_color = feature.properties.fill;
    var stroke_color = feature.properties.stroke;
    console.log('title', title);
    layer.on('click', (event) => {
      console.log("clicked");
      var value = feature.properties['title'] + 'mm';
      console.log("value", value);
      layer.bindPopup(value).openPopup();
    });
  }
});
 map.addLayer(forecastLayer);
}
```

**For Remove the any layer:**

```
 if (map.hasLayer(forecastLayer)) {
                map.removeLayer(forecastLayer);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: doesnt work. Still getting the same result. The map is disappearing.

Comment: @user7500984 as per image updated in the question. It seems map is visible. check zoom level of map.